# Firebase function get parameter from URL

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I want to have a custom url like `https://<my-project-id>.firebaseapp.com/parameter` such that I have a function that takes in the value '**parameter**'.

Here is what I have for firebase.json rewrites:

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/:bar*", "function": "foo"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

And then for functions/index.js here is my 'foo' function:

```
exports.foo = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log('bar = '+req.query.bar);
  console.info(req.query.bar);
  res.status(200).send(`<!doctype html>
    <head>
      <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      Bar = ${req.query.bar}
    </body>
  </html>`);
});
```

### What works, but is not what I want

If I change firebase.json to the following:

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/**", "function": "foo"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

And write the url like this:

```
https://<my-project-id>.firebaseapp.com/anything?bar=test
```

then it properly gets the **bar** parameter. However, I need to be able to have the url shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `console.log(req.url);` to get the url. Then you just have to extract the last part after the `/`

Comment: This is what I get: `Your client does not have permission to get URL /foo from this server`

Comment: Let me double check

Comment: Oops, so sorry. I had sanitized my code to post and forgot. So I had the function name wrong. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: It should be noted that when you're working with the request and response in Cloud Functions HTTP triggers, you're actually working with the Express.js API.  https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req

Answer (score 2):

Following the other answers, this is what I did to make a "getUser" request work:

```
exports.getUser = (req, res) => {
// https://us-central1-project.cloudfunctions.net/api/user/diegovfeder
// console.log(req.url);

let userId = req.url.split("/");
userId = userId[userId.length - 1];

//console.log(userId);
...
```